# ggplot: add border with given width to geom_point()

Tags: r, ggplot2

The plot below shows circles whose size and grey transparency is given, and with a red border.

```
d_test <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,4,5,4,3,5,2.5),
                     y=c(1,4,3,5,3,5,3,4,3,3),
                     size=runif(10,0,5),
                     alpha=runif(10,0,1))
ggplot() + geom_point(data=d_test,aes(x=x,y=y,size=size,alpha=alpha,stroke=size),shape=21,color="red",fill="black") + theme_bw()
```

[image: Plot 1]

I want to change the width of a border, I therefore specified the 'stroke' parameter. However, as you see below, some circles have now two levels of grey transparency. How to solve that?

```
d_test <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,4,5,4,3,5,2.5),
                     y=c(1,4,3,5,3,5,3,4,3,3),
                     size=runif(10,0,5),
                     alpha=runif(10,0,1))
ggplot() + geom_point(data=d_test,aes(x=x,y=y,size=size,alpha=alpha),shape=21,color="red",fill="black") + theme_bw()
```

[image: Plot 2]

Comment: the red color overlaps the grey color. Thats why you have two levels. Try `ggplot(data=d_test, aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=size,alpha=alpha,stroke=size),shape=21, fill="black") + 
  geom_point(aes(size=size,stroke=size),shape=21, color="red") + 
  theme_bw()`